# cascade foreign key on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I am trying to create UPDATE CASCADE Foreign key reference to a table using below scripts.I am getting error saying it may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.

```
  ALTER TABLE STA_STATIONARY_REQUEST_MASTER  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_STA_STATIONARY_REQUEST_MASTER_REQUESTOR_ID] FOREIGN KEY([REQUESTOR_ID])
    REFERENCES STA_EMPLOYEE_MASTER ([EMPLOYEE_ID])

 ALTER TABLE STA_STATIONARY_REQUEST_MASTER  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_STA_STATIONARY_REQUEST_MASTER_CREATED_BY] FOREIGN KEY([CREATED_BY])
REFERENCES STA_EMPLOYEE_MASTER ([EMPLOYEE_ID])
```

But when I am creating using below scripts it is created successfully.But still i am not able to update the employee id.

```
ALTER TABLE STA_STATIONARY_REQUEST_MASTER   ADD CONSTRAINT       
FK_STA_STATIONARY_REQUEST_MASTER_EMP1
FOREIGN KEY (REQUESTOR_ID) REFERENCES STA_EMPLOYEE_MASTER(EMPLOYEE_ID), 
FOREIGN KEY (CREATED_BY) REFERENCES STA_EMPLOYEE_MASTER (EMPLOYEE_ID)  
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Please help.

Comment: Are there triggers on the tables? If yes, then you usually get this error.

Comment: there are no triggers on that table.